# HTTP server benchmarking with different files

Tags: http, benchmarking

I have an HTTP server that accepts POST requests with files (the content of the request is a file).

I want to benchmark it with a directory of files.

I tried a tool called ab (Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool) and managed to benchmark with 1 file that I sent as the post data, the problem is that I need each request to use a different file, is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try to [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) and create a [Lua](https://www.lua.org/) script to customize your request, for example, something this is a basic counter:

```
counter = 0

request = function()
    if counter % 100 == 0 then
        path = "/"
    else
        path = path .. counter .. "/"
    end
    wrk.headers["X-Counter"] = counter
    counter = counter + 1
    return wrk.format(nil, path)
end
```

This script will query:

```
/
/1/
/1/2/
/1/2/3
```

And you call it using:

```
$ wrk -c100 -d10 -t2 -s counter.lua http://0:8080/
```

- `-c100` is to keep 100 connections open
- `-d10` Duration of the test (10 seconds)
- `-t2` Number of threads to use
- `-s counter.lua` Use the `counter.lua` script

Comment: is it possible to give it a directory of files and make it transfer each as POST request using Lua ?

Comment: @Musmus yes, but you will have to code/build your script

Comment: Will there be a race condition with counter = counter + 1?